# CakePHP - refresh element/view cell using ajax

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to build a way to update a user profile one question at a time. 
Essentially I want a div on my page that displays a form that lets the user submit the most important information, say firstname. When that has been filled out (success on the form) I want to refresh that div and show the second most important form, for say lastname, or if that is already filled in then birthday and so on.

Much like linkedin prompts you to add one more piece to your profile.

How would you do it?

My first thought was to use elements. But I need to fetch existing profile data to populate the form and how would the element get that data, abusing requestAction is not an option.

So I guess I in that case need to call a controller action that determines which element should be rendered, renders it to a variable and submits that (response->body) in json to the js that updates the page. Seems a bit .. unclean but should work.

Then we have view cells. They seem ideal for the task until I want to call them via ajax. That is not possible right?

So how would you go about to build something like that?
A form that needs to have the ability to be prepopulated with data if there is any and then refreshed automagically to display the form for the next piece of info needed.

Answer (score 1):

View cells can't really be used in AJAX requests. This is not what they thought for.

The best thing you could do, if you want to keep the cell, is to make sure you followed [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) properly and put all your business logic into the model layer.

Now have a separate controller and action that is reachable from the outside throught a request (a cell is not) and return the data as JSON from there using the same code.

You could try to instantiate the cell in the controller action as well and send it's output. But honestly, I think that's a pretty fugly way of doing it.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. I simplified the question a bit since the cell mostly just calls the model at this moment.

Good to have confirmed that a cell can't be reached via ajax at least.